# php variables from url into a function, returning an error

Tags: php

I can echo the species and bone variables, but when I put then into the following code I get `Notice: Undefined variable: species in <filename>`. Any ideas?

```
  $species = $_GET['species'];
  echo $species ;

  $bone = $_GET['bone'];
  echo $bone ;

  function myfilter($row){
      return ($row['commonName']== $species && $row['elementName']==$bone);
  }
  $result = array_filter($data, 'myfilter');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not going to make what you are trying to achieve. When you are using `myfilter` as a callback function for `array_filter` it will not get the variables outside that function.That's why `species` and `bone` variables are triggering **Notice**. You need to make the variables accessible from callback by using either the super global $_GET (that's not preferable by me ) or passing the species, bone in the callback in `array_filter` like below.

**Using the super global**

```
<?php

function myfilter($row){
      return ($row['commonName'] == $_GET['species'] && $row['elementName'] == $_GET['bone']);
  }
  
$result = array_filter($data, 'myfilter' );
```

**Passing variables in callbacks**

```
<?php

$species = $_GET['species'];
$bone = $_GET['bone'];

$result = array_filter($data, function ( $row ) use ( $species, $bone )
{
return ($row['commonName'] == $species && $row['elementName'] == $bone );
});
```